# Regex for decimal or fraction

Tags: java, regex

Right now I have a regex where it checks if the string in a decimal format or not:

```
-?\\d+(?:.\\d+)//any positive or negative number, including decimals
```

If I wanted to create a regex for a fraction, which may also consist of decimals, such as:

- 3.1/2.6
- 1.00/5.00

Would the following be valid?

```
 -?\\(d+(?:.\\d+)|d+(?:.\\d+)/d+(?:.\\d+))//a decimal OR a fraction(including decimals)
```

Comment: Why did you lose the "\\" in front of some of the the `d+` in your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to support positive/negative integers, decimals with optional fractional part:

```
-?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?\\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ8oI1/2)

Or if you're using Java's `String#matches()` method then use this regex:

```
-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?
```

Comment: You probably wouldn't want the `-?` in the denominator, however.

Comment: Agreed negative denominator doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why did you add the two `\\b`? Given the phrasing of the question, the pattern will be used to match an entire string, which means using `matches()`, so they are meaningless.

Comment: @Andreas: If numbers are the only thing in a line then use it would be just `-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?`

Comment: 1) You are referring to a "line", but nothing in the question says anything about the input being from a multi-line source like a text file. 2) Alternative to `String.matches()` is `Matcher.matches()`, which is used when you precompile the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate solution.

#### Regex to Validate Numbers(Positive,negative,decimal) and Fractions

```
/[-]?[0-9]+[,.]?[0-9]*([\/][0-9]+[,.]?[0-9]*)*/g
```

Source: https://digitalfortress.tech/tricks/top-15-commonly-used-regex/

[Demo](https://www.regexpal.com/94462)