# How to build a java parser for vectors?

Tags: java, parsing, tokenize

I am trying to build a parser for vectors (and eventually will do it for matrices)

In my test class, I have this:

```
Parser parser = new Parser();
        try {
          VectorExpressionNode expression = parser.parse("{1.2, 4.2, 5.2}+{1.0, 2.0,3.0}");
          System.out.println("The value of the expression is "+expression.getValue()[0]);
        }
        catch (ParserException e) {
          System.out.println("Parser Exception" + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (EvaluationException e) {
          System.out.println("Evaluation Exception " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

But it's not parsing the line. I am sure that the problem was with the regular expression I am using for arrays. Here's the method I am using (FYI: Tokenize - class that tokenizes the input tokens)

```
private static Tokenizer createExpressionTokenizer()
      {
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer();

        tokenizer.add("[+-]", Token.PLUSMINUS);
        tokenizer.add("[*]", Token.MULT);


        tokenizer.add("\\{\\s*(\\d+(\\s*,\\s*\\d+)*\\s*)?\\}", Token.ARRAY);//I think the program doesn't get this
        return tokenizer;
      }
```

When I ran the program, I noticed that it can't pass through the "if(m.find())" line. This is the method that reads the tokens from the input:

```
public void tokenize(String str) throws Exception {
        String s = new String(str);
        int totalLength = s.length();
        tokens.clear();
        while(!s.equals("")) { 
            int remaining = s.length();
            boolean match = false;
            for (TokenInfo info: tokenInfos) {
                Matcher m = info.regex.matcher(s);
                System.out.println(m.toString());
                if (m.find()) { //the program is not entering this block
                    match = true;

                    String tok = m.group().trim();
                    tokens.add(new Token(info.token, tok, totalLength - remaining));

                    s = m.replaceFirst("");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!match) throw new Exception(); //as a result, throws this exception

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your regular expression is wrong. '\d' just matches one single digit. You can test your regular expression on this site: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Btw.: The line `String s = new String(str);` is useless and evil as it creates a new `String` object. There is no need to "clone" a `String` as it is immutable.

Comment: Do you want to parse vectors of exactly three elements (which are numbers), or any number of elements?

Comment: Check out the accepted answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34728460/regex-for-decimal-or-fraction ... use that regex instead of \d in your regex so that it will match decimals/fractions instead of digits.

Comment: @isnot2bad I want to parse vector with any number of elements of any type: integers, doubles etc. How can I change my code in order to accomplish that?

Comment: @mettleap How should it eventually look like? I have tried to replace \d with that expression, but it gives a compilation error

Comment: @isnot2bad, current regex does support vectors of any number of elements

Comment: Here is a regex (but it is extremely unreadable): \{\s*((-?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:/\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\b)+(\s*,\s*(-?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:/\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\b)+)*\s*)?\} ... I tested this on https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output ... if you use it in java, you have to replace \ with \\ ... this matches strings like {1} OR {1.2} OR {1, 3.64, 5.0}